# Image Noise handling and edge direction determination

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, graph-algorithm

I would like to implement the guidepath tracking system. Suppose that user will see the following view:

[image]

Therefore, my algorithm need to scan from bottom to top for guidepath direction confirmation. I use the HSV color filter to create the mask and then create the skeleton of mask. The result like following:

[image]

But you can see that there exist some noise (red circle). How can I remove this?

Also, how to determine the sub-guidepath direction (like blue arrow)? Someone suggest me to use Sobel Operator. But this approach seem that only can implement edge detection, not for edge direction determination.

The following also the noise simple:
[image]

Comment: It seem that you got some idea. Could you tell me you method?

Comment: Well, first we'd set up a contract and a payment plan...

Comment: ok. write down your bank account here

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: So, could you give me some suggestion? I am serious need your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple algorithm yourself rather than looking for one. Since you've got the skeleton, you can find the junctions, then walk along each segment, if the segment length is shorter than a certain value then just remove it.

To find the direction of the path segment, can do the same, from junction to the end point of the segment draw a line, then look at the angle of this line, and quantize that angle to get one of the four main directions.